# Get runOutput from python activity (not notebook activity) in ADF V2

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I need to receive the runOutput from python activity in ADF.
In Notebook activity we can receive it using  `@ {activity ('databricks notebook activity name').output.runOutput}`.
But same thing when I am trying to do using python activuty, it is not working even though I am exiting notebook with  `dbutils.notebook.exit('my message)`.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add additional information like activity configuration and expected result?

Comment: It is just a python activity which is pointing to the python script placed in dbfs workspace and I need to get the output back to the next adf activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and not able to get the `runOutput` of Python script like we get in Notebook activity.

`dbutils.notebook.exit('my message')`

I have used the above script in my `.py` file.

[image]

As per my repro, `runOutput` might not be there for python activity. You can try this workaround where I am able to get the Output from [REST API job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs#request-7) runs.

First extract the particular run id of the python activity from the above output.

```
@string(last(split(activity('Python1').output.runPageUrl,'/')))
```

[image]

Then use web activity to get the details of that particular run with Bearer token as authorization.

[image]

**URL:** `https://< databricks-instance >/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get-output?run_id=@{variables('run_id')}`

**For Header:** give name as `Authorization` and for value give `Bearer < your databricks bearer token>`

In the logs of the above web activity output, you can find the python activity output.

```
@string(activity('Web1').output.logs)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This surely works but what will happen when the code will be promoted to higher environment or if the token expires, in that case how shall I use the token? any idea.

Comment: `dbutils.notebook.exit('my message')` this is same for both Notebook and Python activities, and it will return the same for both. The above access token will expire after 90 days I think, and the same token will be used for the Databricks linked service also. So, the above can be same as calling notebook activity.